# Is it necessary to convert query result to .ToList() before using FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am facing transaction related issues such as

> *the transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests*

or

> *New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.*

While I investigated for this error over internet I could see many blogs pointing towards using `ToList()` in for loops etc.

My question is I have too frequently used `FirstOrDefault()` in my project, should we always use `.ToList()` before doing `FirstOrDefault()`, or it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: I don't think that .tolist()).first() is causing the issue. Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ToList()` method takes the query result in the memory so you no longer requires active connection with database for that.If you have large memory avilable then you can go for `.ToList()`

You must be facing this issue for nested database calls i.e in loops